# Photo Editing Extension Questions (iOS 8)

Tags: swift, ios8, photo

I am encountering some issues in Photo Editing Extensions, please help.

1) Image does not seem to changed.

In Photo Editing extension, if I want to commit an already filter image (self.filterImage), I create a JPEG representation, write to the output rendered URL... but when "Done", the image replaced, but when I view them in iPhoto or Image Capture, they are still the same.

```
func finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((PHContentEditingOutput!) -> Void)!) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(CLong(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT), 0)) {
    let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: self.input)
    output.adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier:"virtualgs.retrocam", formatVersion:"1.0", data:nil)

    let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.filterImage!, 1.0)
    jpegData.writeToURL(output.renderedContentURL, atomically: true)
    completionHandler?(output)
  }
}
```

2) Does not support gestures?

I implemented swiping, make sure that User Interaction Enabled is on, but nothing happened when swipe. Does swipe or other gestures work successfully for others?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a valid, not nil NSData representation of your changes. If your adjustmentData.data is nil the system believes no changes were performed. As Apple describes in the documentation, it's best to provide a description or serialisation of your edits that can be used at startContentEditingWithInput to recreate the last editing session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to make it destructive (rather than recreate the last session) - i.e., the new photo replaces the old photo. Can you point me to any example codes?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? As a user, I rely on the fact that I can undo/refine my edits if needed.